Docker Kafka and Zookeeper Issue
I am new to docker and when i am trying to run kafka and zookeeper,
i see these issues,
in zookeeper:
2024-04-29 15:50:44,031 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@686] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2024-04-29 15:50:44,057 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:ZKDatabase@117] - zookeeper.snapshotSizeFactor = 0.33
2024-04-29 15:50:44,060 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:FileSnap@83] - Reading snapshot /bitnami/zookeeper/data/version-2/snapshot.0
2024-04-29 15:50:44,124 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:FileTxnSnapLog@404] - Snapshotting: 0x106 to /bitnami/zookeeper/data/version-2/snapshot.106
2024-04-29 15:50:44,148 [myid:1] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@132] - PrepRequestProcessor (sid:0) started, reconfigEnabled=false
2024-04-29 15:50:44,156 [myid:1] - INFO  [main:ContainerManager@64] - Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000
2024-04-29 15:51:02,202 [myid:1] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@218] - Creating new log file: log.107
2024-04-29 15:51:03,598 [myid:1] - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@413] - Expiring session 0x10000e9ffe20001, timeout of 18000ms exceeded
2024-04-29 15:54:15,719 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-13:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
2024-04-29 15:54:16,741 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-14:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
2024-04-29 15:54:16,742 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-17:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
2024-04-29 15:54:16,743 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-15:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856
2024-04-29 15:54:21,750 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-19:NIOServerCnxn@370] - Exception causing close of session 0x0: Len error 1195725856

and in kafka:
[2024-04-29 15:53:58,857] WARN [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1195725856 larger than 104857600)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:105)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:989)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:892)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-04-29 15:53:58,860] WARN [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1195725856 larger than 104857600)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:105)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:989)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:892)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-04-29 15:54:03,873] WARN [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1195725856 larger than 104857600)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:105)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:989)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:892)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-04-29 15:57:33,321] INFO Terminating process due to signal SIGTERM (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2024-04-29 15:57:33,323] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2024-04-29 15:57:33,323] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] Starting controlled shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2024-04-29 15:57:33,371] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] Controlled shutdown succeeded (kafka.server.KafkaServer)


i tried kafka heap opts, no use and tried increasing the kafka memory, couldn't get the issue, and my configuration,
zoo1:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.5.9-debian-10-r99
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
      ZOO_PORT_NUMBER: 2181
      ZOO_TICK_TIME: 40000
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "true"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka/zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./kafka/zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/datalog:/datalog

  kafka1:
    image: bitnami/kafka:2.8.1-debian-10-r98
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_CFG_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100
      KAFKA_CFG_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 10485760
      KAFKA_CFG_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES: 10485760
      KAFKA_CFG_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 104857600
      KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka/zk-single-kafka-single/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo1

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka1:9092"
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M -Xss180K -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication"
    depends_on:
      - kafka1

